# Question about direct sums of Hilbert Space Conway 1.6.2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

The following question is from Conway's functional analysis text: "Let $(\mathrm{X}, \Omega)$ be a measurable space, let $\mu_{1}, \mu_{2}$ be measures defined on $(\mathrm{X}, \Omega)$, and put $\mu=\mu_{1}+\mu_{2}$. Show that the map $V: L^{2}(X, \Omega, \mu) \rightarrow L^{2}\left(\mathrm{X}, \Omega, \mu_{1}\right) \oplus$ $L^{2}\left(X, \Omega, \mu_{2}\right)$ defined by $V f=f_{1} \oplus f_{2}$, where $f_{j}$is the equivalence class of $L^{2}\left(X, \Omega, \mu_{j}\right)$ corresponding to $f$, is well defined, linear, and injective. Show that $V$ is an isomorphism iff $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ are mutually singular."

$Vf$ is well defined
since if $V f=f_{1} \oplus f_{2}=f_{1}^{\prime} \oplus f_{2}^{\prime}$
then $\left\|f_{1}-f_{2}^{\prime}\right\|_{\mu_{1}}=\left\|f_{2}-f_{2}^{\prime}\right\|_{\mu_{2}}=0$
$\Rightarrow \quad f_{1}^{\prime} \equiv f_{1} \quad f_{2} \equiv f_{2}^{\prime} .$
Linearity is obvious. Injective: If
$V f=f_{1} \oplus f_{2}=V f^{\prime}$ then $\left\|f-f^{\prime}\right\|_{\mu_{1}}=\left\|f-f^{\prime}\right\|_{\mu_{2}}$
so $\left\|f-f^{\prime}\right\|_{\mu}=0.$

Where I'm more shaky is regarding the last part. It seems that $V$ is always an isometry, since
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle f, g\right\rangle=\int f g d \mu &=\int fg d \mu_{1}+\int fg d \mu_{2} \\
&=\int f_{1} g_{1} d \mu_{1}+\int f_2 g_2d\mu_{2},\\
&=\left\langle f_{1} \otimes f_{2}, g_1 \oplus g_{2}\right\rangle .
\end{aligned}
$$

If $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ are mutually singular, then $V$ is surjective. Let $A$ be such at $\mu_{1}(B)=0$ for all measurable $B \subseteq A$ and  $\mu_{2}(B)=0 \quad$ for all measurable $B \subseteq A^{c}$
Then for all $f_{1} \in L^{2}\left(\mu_{1}\right) \quad f_{2} \in L^{2}\left(\mu_{2}\right)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f=f_{1} 1_{A^{c}}+f_{2}1_{A} \text { satisfies } \\
&V f=f_{1} \oplus f_{2} .
\end{aligned}
$$
If $\mu_{1}$ and $ \mu_{2}$ are not mutually singular, then $V$ is not surjective, since then there exists E so that $\left.\mu_{1}( E\right) \mu_{2}\left(E)>0\right.$, so for example there is no element in $L^{2}(\mu)$ mapping to $1_{E} \oplus 0$.

Does this logic make sense? Am I missing something here? What additional details would be needed shore up the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the above looks good to me, but I'm a bit sketched out by your last line. I would complete the proof using a similar idea but without the two negations: Show if $V$ is surjective, then $\mu_1\perp\mu_2$.

Indeed, take $f$ with $Vf=1\oplus 0$, then $f=1$ $\mu_1$ a.e. on $X$, i.e. there exists an $S\subset X$ with $\mu_1(X\setminus S)=0$ and $f=1$ on $S$. However, $f=0$ $\mu_2$ a.e. on $S$, so that $\mu_2(S)=0$ and $\mu_1$ is concentrated on $S$, while $\mu_2$ is concentrated on $X\setminus S$.

Comment: Awesome thanks @operatorerror! I guess it is better to give a direct proof when possible!